# How to get utf8 decoded string from Decodable?

Tags: swift, utf-8, codable

The issue is that I have a json data contains and encoded string, example:

```
let jsonData = "{ \"encoded\": \"SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh\" }".data(using: .utf8)
```

What I need is to get the decoded value of "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh" string.

Actually I could get the desired output by implementing:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let result = try! decoder.decode(Result.self, from: jsonData!)

if let data = Data(base64Encoded: result.encoded), let decodedString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(decodedString) // Hello World!
}
```

What I had to do is:

- convert the encoded string That I got from the json (`result.encoded`) to Data object
- Reconvert the data object to a string again.

However, it seems to be more than just a one step to achieve it, is there better approach(es) to be followed for such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to handle encoded string for a `Decodable`, actually you don't even have to declare the property as `String`, just directly declare it as `Data`.

So for your case, what you should do is to edit `encoded` to as:

```
struct Result: Decodable {
    var encoded: Data
}
```

thus:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let result = try! decoder.decode(Result.self, from: jsonData!)

let decodedString = String(data: result.encoded, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
print(decodedString ?? "") // decodedString
```

---

Keep in mind that it is a pretty similar case to handling *Dates* for decodables, as an example consider that we have the following json data:

```
let jsonData = "{ \"timestamp\": 1527765459 }".data(using: .utf8)
```

Obviously, you won't receive `timestamp` as number and convert it to a Date object, instead you would declare it as `Date`:

```
struct Result: Decodable {
    var timestamp: Date
}
```

thus:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
// usually, you should edit decoding strategy for the date to get the expected result:
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970

let result = try! decoder.decode(Result.self, from: jsonData!)
print(result.timestamp) // 2018-05-31 11:17:39 +0000
```