# Base 64 Decoding

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting a base64 string from the server as below

```
eyJhY3IiOjIsInN1YiI6IjNmZDFhNzQwLWJjZTItMTAzNS04NDUxLWVkODRlMTM4MmFhMiIsImF1ZCI6IjZjZjY3M2ZkLTlkODEtNDU5OS04MGJkLWM5ODRiMmNiZDQ2NSIsIm...
```

I tried to decide this string with following code (As string Extension)

```
//: ### Base64 decoding a string
func base64Decoded() -> String? {
    guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) else { return nil }
    return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
}
```

But it retunes nil.

Also tried with below code (From [GIT](https://gist.github.com/ericdke/1eaed835eef167b9f12c))

```
guard let plainData = (serverString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
    fatalError()
}

let base64String = plainData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
print(base64String) // Zm9v
// Decoding
if let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)),
    let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        print(decodedString) // foo
}
```

But still, I am not able to read the Base64 string coming from the server. Please suggest what am I doing wrong here in decoding the string coming from the server.

Comment: Perhaps this https://stackoverflow.com/q/29152706/1187415 ? Is the length of the Base64 string a multiple of 4?

Comment: try with `Data(base64Encoded: self, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)`

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50710799/5501940) helpful to your issue?

Comment: @MartinR thanks, It helps. Length was not in multiple of 4,

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing the point of base64 encoding.

What you get is an UTF8 string which represents any data. By decoding this string you get data. These data may or may not be a string and in your case they are as it seems NOT.

Using a simple online tool I found out the string you pasted here converts to:

```
{"acr":2,"sub":"3fd1a740-bce2-1035-8451-ed84e1382aa2","aud":"6cf673fd-9d81-4599-80bd-c984b2cbd465","
```

now you get the data from `Data(base64Encoded:` then you are probably looking for `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:` to get a dictionary out of these data.

But there is no reason at all to convert base64 string to data and then to UTF8 string. Your method should look like:

```
func base64Decoded() -> Data? {
    return Data(base64Encoded: self)
}
```

with which you may then do whatever you want like:

```
if let data = serverString.base64Decoded(), let dictionary = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String: Any] {
    // Do something with dictionary
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below one:

```
guard let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)  else{
 return 
} 
let someString = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```